# Clone a <tr> and modify the clone's content in JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, clone

I'm stuck with a problem. I currently have a simple `<table>` that looks like this:

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr id="kc_keychain_1">
    <td class="td-kc-id"> kc_keychain_1 </td>
    <td class="td-kc-name"> Keychain 1 </td>
    <td>
        <p>my key</p>
        <p>my second key</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="kc_keychain_10">
    <td class="td-kc-id"> kc_keychain_10 </td>
    <td class="td-kc-name"> Keychain 10</td>
    <td>
        <p>ma clé</p>
        <p>Clé 005V</p>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I also have some JavaScript code, that aims at cloning a specific row, modifying the `.tc-kc-id` and `.tc-kc-name` cells of the cloned row, and finally adding the cloned and modified row to the table:

```
var clonedTr = document.querySelector('#' + id).cloneNode(true);

//$(clonedTr).find(".td-kc-id").innerText = "test";
//$(clonedTr).find(".td-kc-name").innerText = "test";

document.querySelector('tbody').appendChild(clonedTr);
```

It clones and adds the cloned row without any problem. But the commented code doesn't work. What I try in the commented code is to get specific cells thanks to their classname, and then change their innerText property.

But the innerText of the cells remain unchanged. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: `.innerText` is a JS property that is found in the DOM node, not the jQuery object. Have you tried `$(clonedTr).find(".td-kc-id")[0].innerText `?

Comment: Or `$(clonedTr).find(".td-kc-id").text("test");`

Comment: @ChrisG your answer is working! Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks @Terry for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ChrisG, a possible working solution is:

```
$(clonedTr).find(".td-kc-id").text("test");
```